# Light protection for SQLite database on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, security, sqlite, encryption

There are a bunch of questions on how to protect a SQLite database on the iPhone here. Those questions are mostly about:

- preventing data tampering;
- protecting user's personal data using a passwords that should be entered by a user.

but we have a bit different situation:

- we have an app that is distributed with a sqlite database;
- the database contains publicly available information, but gathering all that information in one place requires some effort, and we don't want competitors to have a simple way to access our data;
- all the database content is available through the application UI, basically the purpose of the app is to nicely present that data. So it is possible to recreate the database through the UI, while there are about 50k records x 40 fields per record, which are going to be updated with each version, so manual scraping will take some time. Also it's probably possible to use some automated screen scraping to extract the data, but again it requires some effort;
- because of the previous point, we are not looking for some industrial grade data protection, we just want to prevent anybody from accessing the application bundle on a jailbroken device and copying the database out of it.

I think that we need some kind of fancy obfuscation of the column contents. Probably we should encrypt the columns using some key that is unique to the app, and can't be accessed by anybody else (if such key exist in the AppStore).

Any suggestions and best practices are appreciated.

Comment: FYI - any legitimate user of your app has access to the ipa file in iTunes. Anyone can simply unzip the ipa file and see all of your files including the database. So some sort of data encryption or obfuscation is required. On a Mac look in **~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications**

Comment: You probably need to use SqlCipher, an encrypted version of SQLite.  Of course, you then need some way to obfuscate the password/key, but that's a different issue.  (Encrypting individual columns is far less secure in most cases.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer my own question — eventually we used the *SQLCipher*, and it worked great, the performance impact was negligible, while cracking it is probably harder than screen scraping the app.